# Container for Spring Integration similar to (Camel + ServiceMix)

Tags: apache-camel, spring-integration, apache-servicemix

Is there container that could be used with Spring Integration in manner similar to Apache Camel + ServiceMix ?

Or maybe there is way to do routing in ServiceMix using SI?

Answer (score 1):

A container is not required (unless, perhaps, you are using an HTTP inbound endpoint); in any case, you can conveniently use Spring Boot to launch your Spring Integration apps, regardless of whether you are using HTTP (it offers the option of using embedded tomcat or jetty).

Comment: I know it could be used on it's own and It's not about http. I'm interested in kind of SOA container or some kind of ESB. My goal is to scale and run my SI project on cluster. But thanks for response.

Comment: You can run your app in a Spring XD container, which will take care of failover etc (it uses zookeeper to detect container loss), or on something like cloudfoundry.